# Why is my Custom CRS undefined in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am trying to create a custom CRS in QGIS and the proj parameters given are as follows:

```
proj +ellps=sphere +a=127.4 +e=0 +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=-32 +lat_ts=60 +x_0=8 +y_0=110
```

I used these parameters in Settings > Custom CRS in QGIS to create the Custom CRS. But when I created a grid using the new CRS it says 'CRS undefined'. What is the correct way to define this CRS in QGIS?

Comment: What's the sense of the `proj` at the start?

Comment: I'm not sure that 'e' can be zero. Try setting +b=127.4 instead. Do you mean those values to be in meters or kilometers?

Answer (score 1):

`+ellps=sphere` expands to `a=6370997.0      b=6370997.0`.

If you want a sphere of a different radius, just use `+a` and `+b`.

Answer (score 0):

You go:

Settings> Custom CRS...

Click the green plus to create a new CRS.

Give it a name and Parameters.

Then you can apply it to a layer.

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more clear. I have done this, but when I use the new CRS I get a message saying 'CRS undefined'. I have edited the question to make it clearer.